# how to save and retrieve application info to shared preference in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gridview, sharedpreferences, show-hide, android-applicationinfo

I want to hide app icon from grid view and save it.
I can save application info to shared preferences as mutable set string and get it but cant convert string to application info and show in my grid view

my app activity

```
private var applist: List<ApplicationInfo>? = null
private var listadaptor: ApplicationAdapter? = null
private var grid: GridView? = null

private var mSelected: ArrayList<Any> = ArrayList()
var context: Activity = this

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps)

   val packageManager = getPackageManager()
   LoadApplications().execute()
   grid = findViewById<View>(R.id.grid) as GridView
   grid!!.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE)
   grid!!.adapter = listadaptor
   grid!!.onItemClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long ->
       val app = applist!![position]
       try {
           val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName)
           intent?.let { startActivity(it) }
       } catch (e: Exception) {
           Toast.makeText(this@appsActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
       }
   }
   grid!!.onItemLongClickListener = AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->

       val position1: String = (position).toString()
       if (mSelected.contains(position1)) {
           mSelected.remove(position1)
           view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) // remove item from list
           // update view (v) state here
           // eg: remove highlight
       } else {
           mSelected.add(position1)
           view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY) // add item to list
           // update view (v) state here
           // eg: add highlight
       }
       button3.setOnClickListener(
               object : View.OnClickListener {
                   override fun onClick(view: View?) {
                       val builder1: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@appsActivity)
                       builder1.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete it ?")
                       builder1.setCancelable(true)
                       builder1.setPositiveButton(
                               "Yes",
                               DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id ->

                                   deleteSelectedItems()
                                   mSelected.remove(position)
                                   listadaptor!!.notifyDataSetChanged()

                                   val app = applist!![position]
                                   listadaptor!!.remove(app)
                               })
                       builder1.setNegativeButton(
                               "No",
                               DialogInterface.OnClickListener { dialog, id -> dialog.cancel() })
                       val alert11: AlertDialog = builder1.create()
                       alert11.show()
                   }
               })
       true
   }
}
private fun deleteSelectedItems() {
    val checked: SparseBooleanArray = grid!!.getCheckedItemPositions()
    if (checked != null) {
        val list: List<Any> = mSelected
        for (i in 0 until checked.size()) {
            if (checked.valueAt(i)) {
                mSelected.remove(checked.keyAt(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
private fun checkForLaunchIntent(list: List<ApplicationInfo>): List<ApplicationInfo> {
    val applist = ArrayList<ApplicationInfo>()
    for (info in list) {
        try {
            if (null != packageManager!!.getLaunchIntentForPackage(info.packageName)) {
                applist.add(info)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(applist, ApplicationInfo.DisplayNameComparator(packageManager))
    return applist
}
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private inner class LoadApplications : AsyncTask<Void?, Void?, Void?>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): Void? {

        applist = checkForLaunchIntent(packageManager!!.getInstalledApplications(
                PackageManager.GET_META_DATA))
        listadaptor = ApplicationAdapter(this@appsActivity,
                R.layout.grid_item, applist!!)
        return null
    }
    override fun onPostExecute(result: Void?) {
        grid!!.adapter = listadaptor
        super.onPostExecute(result)
    }
}
```

items are deleted, but after re-running the application, all installed apps will be restored in gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can look into my open source project [LibTron](https://github.com/atulgpt/LibTron) which has one [module](https://github.com/atulgpt/LibTron/tree/master/libraries/sharedprefdelegates) library for SharedPref written in Kotlin.
To use the library follow the instruction in Project ReadMe
Example to use the library:

```
val applicationInfo: ApplicationInfo = sharedprefrence.Object(name = "sharedprefKey", defaultValue = null)
```

Or in case you want to use it without the help of the you can use GSON, Moshi, Jackson type libraries to convert to/from string to your ApplicationInfo class while saving or reading from the Sharedprefrence

Comment: sorry im beginner. i do not understand .please provide the complete source

Comment: Can you provide a source code of what you are trying to achieve?